# In Angular, I don't want to show the permission-wrapper component tag in DOM

Tags: angular

Don't want to show the permission-wrapper component tag in DOM.

IMPORTANT: the component itself should hide the component's tag (like ), instead of it it should display the template's content in case when it's necessary.

Ex. Create a **permission-wrapper** component that gets the permissions as a parameter and has a template section in it.

In the **permission-wrapper** component check the user's current permissions if permissions are allowed then show component content.
But the permission-wrapper tag doesn't want to show in DOM. If not then again don't show permission-wrapper tag in DOM.

Comment: You could use a structual directive for this instead of a component. https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives

Comment: Dude, stop [closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76667398/in-angular-i-dont-want-to-show-the-permission-wrapper-component-tag-in-dom) and opening the same question again and again.

Comment: There is no actual question to begin with, but more a (very vague) prompt to write code for him.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75999507/angular-semantic-html/76002709#76002709

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the element using javaScript

```
constructor(elementRef:ElementRef){}
ngAfterViewInit()
{
   if (condition)
      this.elementRef.nativeElement.remove()

   //or
   if (condition)
   {
      const element=this.elementRef.nativeElement;
      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
   }
}
```

But really it's a strange requeriment

Answer (score 0):

For components in Angular, I don't think we can hide the component selector in DOM.

if just don't want to see the custom selector, maybe a directive is more suitable for you.

if you always don't want the template shown in the DOM, why not use a service to do the permission check?